# Which transition type gets all the chrome browsing history?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, transition, browser-history

I'm creating an extension to get all the browsing history of my chrome browser. all gets working fine but here is little issue that i want to retrieve all the browsing history like "chrome://history/". I can't retrieve all the history.
 Could anyone suggest me which transition type gets all the browsing history?
Thanks in advance.

here is small part of my code:

```
function onAnchorClick(event) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    selected: true,
    url: event.srcElement.href
  });
  return false;
}

// Given an array of URLs, build a DOM list of those URLs in the
// browser action popup.
function buildPopupDom(divName, data) {
  var popupDiv = document.getElementById(divName);

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  popupDiv.appendChild(ul);

  for (var i = 0, ie = data.length; i < ie; ++i) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data[i];
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));
    a.addEventListener('click', onAnchorClick);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(a);

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

// Search history to find up to ten links that a user has typed in,
// and show those links in a popup.
function buildTypedUrlList(divName) {
  // To look for history items visited in the last week,
  // subtract a week of microseconds from the current time.
  var microsecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
  var oneWeekAgo = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsPerWeek;

  // Track the number of callbacks from chrome.history.getVisits()
  // that we expect to get.  When it reaches zero, we have all results.
  var numRequestsOutstanding = 0;


  chrome.history.search({
      'text': '',              // Return every history item....
      'startTime': oneWeekAgo  // that was accessed less than one week ago.
    },
    function(historyItems) {
      // For each history item, get details on all visits.
      for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; ++i) {
        var url = historyItems[i].url;
        var processVisitsWithUrl = function(url) {
          // We need the url of the visited item to process the visit.
          // Use a closure to bind the  url into the callback's args.
          return function(visitItems) {
            processVisits(url, visitItems);
          };
        };
        chrome.history.getVisits({url: url}, processVisitsWithUrl(url));
        numRequestsOutstanding++;
      }
      if (!numRequestsOutstanding) {
        onAllVisitsProcessed();
      }
    });


  // Maps URLs to a count of the number of times the user typed that URL into
  // the omnibox.
  var urlToCount = {};

  // Callback for chrome.history.getVisits().  Counts the number of
  // times a user visited a URL by typing the address.
  var processVisits = function(url, visitItems) {
    for (var i = 0, ie = visitItems.length; i < ie; ++i) {
      // Ignore items unless the user typed the URL.
      if (visitItems[i].transition != 'typed') {
        //continue;
      }

      if (!urlToCount[url]) {
        urlToCount[url] = 0;
      }

      urlToCount[url]++;
    }

    // If this is the final outstanding call to processVisits(),
    // then we have the final results.  Use them to build the list
    // of URLs to show in the popup.
    if (!--numRequestsOutstanding) {
      onAllVisitsProcessed();
    }
  };
      // This function is called when we have the final list of URls to display.
  var onAllVisitsProcessed = function() {
    // Get the top scorring urls.
    urlArray = [];
for (var url in urlToCount) {
  urlArray.push(url);
    }
```

// Sort the URLs by the number of times the user typed them.
        urlArray.sort(function(a, b) {
          return urlToCount[b] - urlToCount[a];
        });

```
    buildPopupDom(divName, urlArray.slice(0, 2000));
  };
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  buildTypedUrlList("typedUrl_div");
});
```

Comment: So you want to get all history starting with `chrome://history`, is that right?

Comment: yes. do you have any solution? @HaibaraAi

Answer (score 1):

As per your reply from the comments, assuming you want to get all history starting with `chrome://history`, you could use [`chrome.history.search`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-search):

```
chrome.history.search({text: "", maxResults: 10000}, function(results) {
    var ans = results.filter(function(result) {
        return result.startsWith("chrome://history");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But i can't implement this code. It's not displaying any results. @haibara ali

Comment: The problem is in here.  if (visitItems[i].transition != 'typed') {
        //continue;
      }